# Can 「持ち込んだ食品を飲食するのは禁止である。」be simplified for a notification board?

Tags: grammar

I want to write a notification board saying

> Consuming outside food and drink is not allowed.

My attempt is as follows, but I think it can be simplified.

> 持ち込んだ食品を飲食するのは禁止である。

## Update

Bring outside food and drink is fine as long as they are not consumed. This exemption might be useful for those who come to the restaurant after shopping.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To the Update: Even to mean that, people usually use the phrases like:

> - 飲食物の持ち込み*禁止
> - 飲食物の持ち込みお断り
> - 飲食物の持ち込みはお断りしております。(← politer)
> - 飲食物の持ち込みはご遠慮｛ください。/ いただいております。/ 願います。｝(← politer)

etc...

[image]

(You can use these phrases for that purpose because the word 飲食物 is used here; you'd use 食品 or 食料品, not 飲食物, to mean *any* foods / food products, as in: 「食品/食料品の持ち込み禁止」"Bringing in any groceries/foods/food products is not allowed")

But if you want to more clearly say or emphasize that bringing in food and drinks is fine as long as they are not consumed, I think you could write:

> - お持ち込みされたもののご飲食はご遠慮｛ください。/ いただいております。｝
> - 店外からお持ち込みの物の飲食はご遠慮｛ください。/ いただいております。｝
> - 他店にてご購入の商品の飲食はご遠慮｛ください。/ いただいております。｝

*You could spell it as 持ち込み, 持込み or 持込.

Answer (score 11):

How about **飲食物持込禁止**? It is more like for a notification board. (e.g. see http://peragami.com/?p=662 )

Generally, if you want to do this kind of simplification, you can omit particles like の/を, a trivial verb like 〜である, and some 送り仮名.

The sample above can be reduced from 飲食物**の**持込**は**禁止**である** or 飲食物**の**持込**を**禁止**する**.

Although a notion of consuming is also omitted, one can understand it correctly.

Answer (score 5):

I have no idea what the fuss is, Just say,

> 飲食持込禁止{いんしょくもちこみきんし｝

That will get the message across and is the most short and concise way to say this.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on where the sign will be.
If it's at the entrance, those could do fine I suppose.
食物の持込を遠慮してください。
食物の持込は禁止である。

EDIT
If bringing food in is ok then... how about this:
当店の食品以外の飲食は禁止です。
当店の飲食物以外の飲食は禁止です。
当店の食品以外の飲食はご遠慮ください。

Comment: `食物の持込を遠慮してください。` <- sounds unnatural, I'm afraid. [「飲食物の持ち込みはご遠慮ください」](http://i.stack.imgur.com/X8nmk.jpg) would be natural. `食物の持込は禁止である。` <- である on a notice like that would be quite unnatural.

Answer (score 1):

> 飲食物の店内持込みは、固く禁止しております。

（日本のデバートなどで見かけられる表現です。）

> We prohibit your bringing in items from outside of stores, especially not those of drinks and something to eat.

( we often use here is our department, shopping stores and mall's line stores in japan.)

Here is my side story about your suggestive expression from our japanese view.
We're proverbly well known this  type ' firm' express. in japanese common usage and saw often around.

just above and your notifying note both also frequently and especially saw in Japanese shopping mall or department stores' cafe and stores recently. We're commonly forbitten to take into our own food and drinks-

i mean that are bought outside of the shop you want to enter. so, this notice says that stopping your bringing in the shop from outside to eat and drink and  items not-buying there and near around.

there often you see places to buy things likewise. mostly where you can go and buy to get anything you eat and drink. you eat and dink in dued places and purchasing items displayed around near, to consuming contributing that shop and shopping mall, department store, that belongs to that shop, for sake eithier.

maybe our ritual is a little bit different from yours.

I'm appreciated if my writing in is rather helpful for your sake, than i excet it.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Japanese Stackexchange. It is acceptable to write answers in Japanese as well if you feel that you can provide a better answer in Japanese. このサイトで日本語で答えてもいいです。